# Issue in using ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am working with a `Listview` that populates using an `adapter`.
In the `getCount()` method of adapter when I print the size of the vector which is passes to the adapter I get 3. 
But the `getView()` method is called 9 times. When I print a text in `getView()` method it is getting printed 9 times.

Can anybody tell the correct way to populate `ListView`..???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many rows are displayed in listview..??

Comment: what adapter are you using? Share your code!

Comment: It's ok. It's the way how ListView works. getView may be called more then count of ListView items. Check this tutoril http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: This is nice tutorial for you. [android-tutorial/android-listview](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview). I expected you will be helpful from this link. Best of luck!

Comment: If you have not setup the adapter class properly there are high chances that the getView method gets called multiple time. how many time getView gets called has nothing to do with getCount. getCount simply returns the number of items in the list.  you should reuse the convertview in getView method which would mostly solve your problem.